# Is it ok to modify a dependency after injection?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, dao

I would like to use dependency injection to specify the table name and permissible columns for a data object class.  My plan is to do something like:

```
class DatabaseTable implements DatabaseTableInterface {
    protected $_table_name;  
    protected $_columns; 

    public function __construct($table_name, $columns){
        $this->_table_name = $table_name;
        $this->_columns = $columns;
    }

    public function addColumn($new_column) {
        ...
    }

    public function getColumns() {
        ...
    }

    ...
}

class UserObject implements UserObjectInterface {
    protected $_table;    // Should be a DatabaseTable object

    public function __construct($table){
        $this->_table = $table;    // Inject a DatabaseTable object here
    }

    // Set the value of a particular property of this User
    public function setValue($column, $value){
        // Only allow if the column is present in the list of permissible columns in the DatabaseTable object
        ...
    }
}
```

Which could be used, for example:

```
// Initial table parameters
$user_table = new DatabaseTable("user", ["id", "name", "email"]);

// Create a new user object
$user = new User($user_table);
```

The `addColumn` method basically adds a column to the whitelist for a particular table.  Multiple data object types might need access to the same table, which is why I factor this into a separate class.  Furthermore, it should be possible to dynamically add columns to the whitelist at any time, even after a particular object has been instantiated:

```
// This is OK
$user->setValue("name", "Alex");

// This is not OK (yet)
$user->setValue("marbles", 0);

// Add "marbles" column to the whitelist
$user_table->addColumn("marbles");

// Now it is OK!
$user->setValue("marbles", 0);
```

I know that in PHP5, this will work because objects are assigned by "reference".  But, am I violating any design principles by allowing a dependency to be modified after being injected into its dependent?